# Alguien realizo una app con el backend en Railway y frontend en Vercel y tuvo problemas con la peticion PUT?

Tags: reactjs

Tengo un blog que funciona con cors, me trae el post creado  ademas de datos de login,como username y password,una vez logeado me funciona el post que esta base de datos MongoDB. Pero al querer hacer la peticion POST de crear post o la peticion PUT de update no me edita ni me envia un nuevo post, la app esta en REACT, el front esta en Vercel y el back en Railway.

el error de origines cruzados no da problemas ya que lo de la base de datos si lo recibe, vi los logs de railway y no arroja ningun error,  la app funciona con los post , pero el error que salta al darle click al boton que llama a updatePost  es un error 500 que falla del servidor

esto eh intentado para el back

```
app.put('/post/:id', uploadMiddleware.single('file'), async (req, res) => {
  // Configurar los encabezados CORS
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'url');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT');

  let newPath = null;
  if (req.file) {
    const { originalname, path } = req.file;
    const ext = originalname.split('.').pop(); // Obtener la extensión del archivo
    newPath = `${path}.${ext}`; // Agregar la extensión al final de la ruta del archivo
    fs.renameSync(path, newPath);
  }

  const { token } = req.cookies;
  try {
    const { id, title, summary, content } = req.body;
    const postDoc = await Post.findById(id);
    const isAuthor = JSON.stringify(postDoc.author) === JSON.stringify(info.id);
    if (!isAuthor) {
      return res.status(400).json({ message: 'you are not the author' });
    }
    await postDoc.update({
      title,
      summary,
      content,
      cover: newPath ? newPath : postDoc.cover,
    });

    res.status(204).end(); // Devolver un código de estado 204 (sin contenido)
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'server error' });
  }
});
```

y esto en el front

````
export default function EditPost() {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
  const [summary, setSummary] = useState('');
  const [content, setContent] = useState('');
  const [files, setFiles] = useState('');
  const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://backend.example.app/post/` + id)
      .then(response => {
        response.json().then(postInfo => {
          setTitle(postInfo.title);
          setContent(postInfo.content);
          setSummary(postInfo.summary);
        });
      });
  }, []);

  async function updatePost(ev, err) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData();
    data.set('title', title);
    data.set('summary', summary);
    data.set('content', content);
    data.set('id', id);
    if (files?.[0]) {
      data.set('file', files?.[0]);

    }
    const response = await fetch(`https://example/post/` + id, {
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        'Referer': 'https://url.app',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer [secret]',
      },
      body: data,
      credentials: 'include',
    });```
````

Comment: Pon en el título el problema _específico_ que estás teniendo. Cualquiera que lea tu pregunta entenderá que quieres que hagan el código por ti, y esa no es la funcionalidad del sitio. Lee [ask] y pulsa en [edit] para corregir tu pregunta.